# TypeError Exception in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm a beginner with python and we started with OOP this week. The program I'm currently doing computes for the area of a rectangle and I've gotten most of the code working, except for the one where the program needs to reject a float input and exit.

Here's my code:

```
le = eval(input("Length:"))
wi = eval(input("Width:"))

def Rec(l, w):
    if l < 0 and w < 0:
        raise ValueError

    total = l * w
    return total

i = True
while i:
    try:
        print("Area:", Rec(le, wi))
        i = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Input is negative!")
        i = False
    except TypeError:
        print("The number is not an integer!")
        i = False
    else:
        break
```

Comment: either take input as int `try: le = int(input("Length:"))` or you can use isinstance() `if isinstance(le,float): `

Comment: `eval(input(...))` is a very bad practice. If you found this in a tutorial, the best advice would be to drop it and use a good one instead.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille it was actually taught to us by our professor so I did not know its a bad practice... I'll keep this in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the type of the input.
Try this:

```
le = eval(input("Length:"))
wi = eval(input("Width:"))
import math

class Rec():
    def __init__(self, l, w):
        self.le = l
        self.wi = w
  
    def area(self):
      if self.le < 0 or self.wi < 0:
          raise ValueError
      elif type(self.le) is float or type(self.wi) is float:
          raise TypeError
      else:
          return self.le * self.wi

i = True
while i:
    try:
        total = Rec(le, wi)
        print("Area:", total.area())
        i = False
    except ValueError:
        print("Input is negative!")
        i = False
    except TypeError:
        print("The number is not an integer!")
        i = False
    else:
        break
```

You could also use `isinstance` instead of `type` by replacing the check with:

```
elif isinstance(self.le,float) or isinstance(self.wi,float):
```

Also you should check whether the length or breadth are negative with `or` instead of ````and````` as both dimensions should be positive.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that and update my code!

Comment: Also use ````is```` instead of ````==```` while checking type as types are singletons

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the input in a check, like this:

```
def checkinput(x):
    if(isinstance(x, int)):
        return x
    else:
        print('Input a non decimal number like 1,2.. n.')
        sys.exit(1) #exit with error code
      
le = checkinput(eval(input("Length:")))
wi = checkinput(eval(input("Width:")))
```

edit: to make this work you should also 'import sys'